# left join where is null and maybe having count() = 0?

Tags: mysql, left-join, having

I have a tables [seller], [advert], and [sale].

Due to a quirk in how my company works, the seller of a sale can be changed for another seller (let us call them orphan sales), but the [sale] table is updated to reflect the new advert.id from the new seller.

I want to count the price for the orphan sales of users that ONLY HAD ORPHAN SALES.

Before having the price, I can't even seem to create a list of users that only had orphan sales.

I am trying to do a left join with where is null so i can get those adverts that have no sales, and then a having count() = 0 so i can get those users that have no sales.

```
SELECT seller.id
FROM seller
JOIN advert ON advert.seller_id = seller.id
JOIN sale orphan ON advert.id = orphan.advert_id
JOIN sale accomplished_sale ON advert.id = accomplished_sale.advert_id
WHERE orphan.id IS NULL
GROUP BY seller.id
HAVING count(accomplished_sale.id) = 0
```

However, what I am getting is every seller that has at least 1 sale without sales, but that have other adverts with sales.

Given that the relationship advert-sale is n->1 I guess that a normal join is just a left join, right? the same thing happens with seller-advert.

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following without join syntax:

```
SELECT seller.id
FROM seller, sale, advert
WHERE advert.seller_id = seller.id
AND advert.id = sale.advert_id
AND sale.id IS NULL
GROUP BY seller.id
HAVING count(accomplished_sale.id) = 0
```

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff Yeah, it's cartesian join. Changed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need  a  left join on one (or more ) tables  you must call it eg: for left join on sale as orphan

```
SELECT seller.id
FROM seller
INNER JOIN advert ON advert.seller_id = seller.id
LEFT JOIN sale orphan ON advert.id = orphan.advert_id
INNER JOIN sale accomplished_sale ON advert.id = accomplished_sale.advert_id
WHERE orphan.id IS NULL
GROUP BY seller.id
HAVING ifnull(count(accomplished_sale.id), 0)  = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your query, I think below query will give you accepted output.

```
SELECT distinct seller.id

FROM seller

JOIN advert ON advert.seller_id = seller.id

JOIN sale orphan ON advert.id = orphan.advert_id

JOIN sale accomplished_sale ON advert.id = accomplished_sale.advert_id

WHERE orphan.id IS NULL

HAVING count(accomplished_sale.id) = 0
```